# Changing background-image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I am trying to change the background image of a div after a period of time automatically using JavaScript (however is the first time that I have used JS).
Nothing in the JavaScript code works; none of those images appear and nothing swaps.

```
    <script type ="text/javascript">
      function displayNextImage() {
          x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
          document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage = "url"+(images[x]);
      }
      function displayPreviousImage() {
          x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
          document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage = "url"+(images[x]);
      }
      function startTimer() {
          setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
      }
      var images = [], x = -1;
      images[0] ='../images/ploutarxos.jpg';
      images[1] ='../images/xatzigiannhs.jpg';
      images[2] ='../images/taylor_swift.jpg';
      images[3] ='../images/selena_gomez.jpg';
      images[4] ='../images/the_weeknd.jpg';
      images[5] ='../images/drake.jpg';
  </script>
    <title>
        Hello world.
    </title>
</head>
<body onload="startTimer()">
    <div id="img" class="swapingImages">
        Oke <br>
        Bla
    </div>
```

Comment: `So I got a problem trying to achieve that and I would appriciate some help. `, if you tell us which problem you have, we probally can help you. Could it be the missing parentheses for the css url? (the one you be using have no effect and wouldn't be used as normal characters)

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Any errors in console?

Comment: You're right, I forget about that .. I'll tel you here in comments and I'll fix my description as well .

Comment: It's not working. I mean none of those images appear and nothing swaps ..

Comment: I tried it locally and adding the parentheses showed me an image. So you want it edit to -----------> `"url(" + images[x] + ")";` - No comments about the code quality it self. I think you have to make your own experiences :-)

Comment: Typo: The `()` need to be part of CSS `url()` syntax, not JavaScript syntax.

Comment: @CagatayUlubay, Yeah that clearly fixed that, thank you ! You can add that as an answer and I can accept that if you want to. :D

Comment: Yea, too late :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One typo I've found is the line below:
`"url"+(images[x]);`
It shoud be:
`"url(" + images[x] + ")";`

```js
var images = ['../images/ploutarxos.jpg',
  '../images/xatzigiannhs.jpg',
  '../images/taylor_swift.jpg',
  '../images/selena_gomez.jpg',
  '../images/the_weeknd.jpg',
  '../images/drake.jpg'
];

var img = document.getElementById("img");

function displayImage(x) {
  img.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[x] + ")";
  img.innerText = images[x];
}
function startTimer() {
  var x = 0;
  displayImage(x);
  setInterval(function() {
    x = x + 1 >= images.length ? 0 : x + 1;
    displayImage(x);
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
swapingImages {
  heigth: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<title>
  Hello world.
</title>

<body onload="startTimer()">
  <div id="img" class="swapingImages"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The format for the background-image CSS style is `url("/path")`:

```
document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + images[x] + '")';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage = "url"+(images[x]);
```

To this

```
document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage = "url("+images[x]+")";
```

Notice the placement of the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new here I won't judge the code quality and only notice you about the mistake you did.

You missed the parentheses at the css propery `url`.

Replace following code:

`"url"+(images[x]);`

With following code:

`"url(" + images[x] + ")";`

Notice that I moved the initial parentheses into the `"` quotes, so they will be seen as actual character and not as typical parentheses to seperate priority of the inner terms like you would do in mathematical terms.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a javascript library called '[UltraPlugin.js](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ultraplugin-js/)'. Importing this library to your page you can use the command: `css("div_id {your code};");` to set the css for div

Comment: The community do not like answers that contains libaries references... I made that mistake too...